# Capitalize letter function in python

Tags: python

I try to write a program with a function to capitalize every first letter in expression with the addition of one dot. For example if I write `hello world` the result must be `H.W.`.

My program is:

```
def initials(Hello World):

    words = input.split(' ')
    initials_words = []
    for word in words:
        title_case_word = word[0].upper() 
        initials_words_words.append(title_case_word)
        output = '. '.join(initials_words)
    return (initials_words)
```

The compilers seems that does nootexit any error but when I try to give an exression such as:`print (initials(Hello World)` the compiler does not give me any result.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
def initials(input_text):
    return "".join(["%s." % w.upper()[0] for w in input_text.split()])
```

Comment: You could use `w[0].upper()` because you don't need to upper-case the whole string, just the first letter. Also `str.format` is a bit better than `%`-formatting (but that's mostly a matter of preference).

Answer (score 2):

I identified several problems:

- You need to change your function signature to take a parameter called `input`. Because that's the variable you `split`. NB: `input` is also a built-in function so using a different variable name would be better.
- Then you use `initial_words_words` instead of `initial_words` inside the loop.
- You assign `output` but you don't use it, it should probably be outside the loop and also returned.
- Not an issue but you don't need `(` and `)` when returning.

So a changed program would look like this:

```
def initials(my_input):

    words = my_input.split(' ')
    initials_words = []
    for word in words:
        title_case_word = word[0].upper() 
        initials_words.append(title_case_word + '.')
    output = ''.join(initials_words)  # or ' '.join(initials_words) if you want a seperator
    return output


print(initials('Hello World'))  # H.W.
```

Answer (score -1):

I see an error when trying to run your code on the 6th line: `initials_words_words.append(title_case_word)`.

> NameError: name 'initials_words_words' is not defined

After Fixing that, the program worked fine. Try changing it to `initials_words.append(title_case_word)`

Comment: There are more problems with the code than just that line. If I make your fix, and run the code, I get a `SyntaxError`.